# Java класс для Bluetooth Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Всем привет. Вот пишу отдельный класс java, который будет отвечать чисто только за управление Bluetooth на android-устройстве. Хотел бы написать два метода, которые:

1. Первый будет включать или выключать Bluetooth и при этом что-бы возвращал true либо false, в зависимости от успеха включения.
2. Второй будет осуществлять поиск устройств и возвращать список найденных устройств. 
   Со вторым методом я так понял не все так гладко, потому как на поиск затрачивается время, а метод выполняется полностью и сразу. Потому я думаю в таком случае использовать callback-функцию.
   А вот с первым проблема тоже кроется в том, что включение Bluetooth выполняется при помощи интента, то есть:

   `Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
   context.startActivity(intent);`

А тут либо в Activity придется переопределять метод onActivityResult(), а я не хотел бы этого делать, потому как хотелось бы сделать классы независимыми друг от друга, следуя принципам инкапсуляции.

Как бы грамотнее это все можно было оформить? Не хочу все нагромождать в одной активности -- это неправильно!

Заранее большое спасибо тем, кто решил помочь! Всем добра и успехов вам!

Comment: В RxPermissions для решения подобного рода проблемы использовали костыль в виде прозрачной активити.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве ответа на свой вопрос нашел следующие решения:

1. В первом случае, что-бы включить или выключить Bluetooth можно вызывать у адаптера `BluetoothAdapter` методы `enable()` и `disable()`. Они возвращают `true`, либо `false` в зависимости от успеха их выполнения.

К примеру мой метод для включения Bluetooth выглядит так:

```
public boolean enableBluetooth(boolean switchBt) {
    if (adapter != null) {
        return (switchBt) ? adapter.enable() : adapter.disable();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Не забудьте где нибудь в конструкторе инициализировать `adapter`:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

2. Во-втором случае, связанным с поиском устройств, я поступил так как и думал до этого, то есть -- использовал callback-методы. Создал интерфейс `Callback` с методом `onDiscoverStatus(int status)`:

   public interface Callback {
       void onDiscoverStatus(int status);
   }

Далее создал `IntentFilter` с отслеживаемыми событиями начала поиска, конца поиска и обнаружения устройства. Затем создал BroadcastReceiver с этими же событиями и зарегистрировал его. По наступлению какого либо события вызывал callback-метод. Далее в другом классе, где надо было получить информацию о наступлении одного из события имплементировал интерфейс `Callback`.

**IntentFilter**

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
this.context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED:
                callback.onStatusDiscover(STARTED);
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED:
                callback.onStatusDiscover(FINISHED);
                break;
            case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
                callback.onStatusDiscover(FOUND);
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device != null) {
                    callback.onStatusDiscover(FOUND);
                    callback.onFound(device);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Допустим подключили интерфейс где нибудь в активности

**MainActivity**

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Callback {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
}

@Override
public void onDiscoverStatus(int status) {
    // что то делаем если пришел статус STARTED или FINISHED
}
```

}

Не забудьте потом по окончанию работы разрегистрировать BroadcastReceiver при помощи метода `context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)`